# How to get react native code from apk file

Tags: android, react-native, apk

I wrote one app in react native, but accidentally near the end of development, my HDD crashes and right now I have only APK file, can I retrieve react native code back just from that apk file?

Comment: at one point or another, most of us learn the hard way why remote repositories are important

Comment: lol, the above comment

Answer (score 39, accepted):

when you unzip the apk file, inside the assets folder, index.android.bundle file is the bundled react source code. rename index.android.bundle to something.js

since something.js is a bundled file (minified/uglified), use some unuglifier/jsbeautifier to make if readable. (also check jsnice)

it's better than nothing.

Answer (score 8):

No, You cannot retrieve actual code but you can get some decompile code

### Installation of apktool:

#### For Macbook

```
brew install apktool
```

#### For Linux

```
apt-get install -y apktool
```

#### For Windows

you can read installion step for window [DOCS](https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/install/)

### Usage

after install `apktool`, unzip apk file by run this command on terminal like this:

```
apktool  d /pathOfApkFile.apk
```

After that you will get `index.android.bundle` file at `pathOfApkFile/assets/index.android.bundle`

than you can use [react-native-decompiler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-decompiler) for decompile `index.android.bundle` file

### Decompile `index.android.bundle` File

you can decompile `index.android.bundle` by run this command

```
npx react-native-decompiler -i ./index.android.bundle -o ./output
```

after that, you will get **JS decompiled file** in `./output` directory

Answer (score 3):

No,I am afraid you cannot retrieve your react native code as if you decompile your apk file it will return you the java code for android but no react native code.

Because,React Native transpile the code into the native language depending upon which OS you want to make a build of either its android or ios.

Comment: Yes, that's true, but I'm hoping I can get it back somehow :(

Comment: ._. As the answer from @GnoStiC says, its all bundled and minified on `assets/index.androind.bundle` file. Please @ristapk modify your accepted answer for everyone who gets here in the future.

Comment: Do you have a reference that shows it is what actually happens? from other answer I gather that it is not converting your code to java but adding another interpreter on top of existing interpreter to read javascript, interpret it to java then interpret it to native.

Comment: we can decompile assets/index.android.bundle file.

Comment: This is wrong, react-native does not transpile the js code into the native platform, rather it bundles the js code into the final package, and runs the js code.